# Is my code is right to make image shortcode

Tags: images, shortcode

I am creating my image shortcode but am I doing it the right way or not.

```
function header_image( $atts ) {
    // [hero-banner img_src="" add_img_class="" alt="" ][/hero-banner]
    $atts = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'image_src' => '',
            'alt' => 'my_image',
            'add_img_class' => '',
            'id' => ''
        ), $atts, 'hero-banner'
    );

    // do shortcode actions here
    $output = "<span class=\"dr-banner\">
                <img src=\"".$atts['image_src']."\" class=\"img-responsive ".$atts['add_img_class']."\" alt=\"".$atts['alt']."\" />
            </span>";

    // return html
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'hero-banner','header_image' );
```

I have a confusion and that is:

`$atts` is a default value holder and if I want to change the image alt attribute or image source is my code is right or wrong

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @kero I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right just need to change $atts variable.

```
// if you want to add image, alt attribute on shortcode statically
$atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
        'image_src' => '',
        'alt' => '',
        'add_img_class' => '',
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts, 'hero-banner'
);


// if you pass image and alt attribute dynamically
$atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
        'image_src' => 'dynamic data',
        'alt' => 'dynamic data',
        'add_img_class' => '',
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts, 'hero-banner'
);
```

It's used when we are using content with closing dynamic parameter.Please find below example

```
 function wrap_content_shortcode_callback($atts, $content, $tag){
      $output = '<span style="font-size: 120%;">' . $content . '</span>';
      return $output;
 }
 add_shortcode('wrap_shortcode','wrap_content_shortcode_callback');
 //use shortcode like this: [wrap_shortcode]test123[/wrap_shortcode]
```

Comment: What is the parameter content used for? Like  `function f_n($atts,$content ) { .....  }`

Comment: Please find updated answer

Comment: Thanks for solving my confusion. I am frustrated by this issue. Once again thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome....happy that i could help you.